# How to display UV Map list as an Enum in Panel?

Tags: python, uv

I want to show the `UV Map` list as an Enum

[image]

I made this with `EnumProperty` but it doesn't change the active `UV Map` from the layer when I change the `Enum`.

[image]

```
def uvmaps(self, context):
    if context.active_object:
        return [(uv.name, uv.name, '') for uv in context.active_object.data.uv_layers]
    else:
        return [('NONE', 'None', ''),]

uv_map : EnumProperty(
    name = 'UV Map',
    items = uvmaps,
)
```

I want to make the `UV Map` list behave like an `Enum`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a [callback](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.EnumProperty) to your `EnumProperty` :

```
def update_uv_map(self, context):
    obj = context.active_object
    if obj is None or obj.data is None or not hasattr(obj.data, "uv_layers"):
        return
    obj.data.uv_layers.active = obj.data.uv_layers[self.uvmap]

uv_map : EnumProperty(
        name='UV Map',
        items=uvmaps,
        update=update_uv_map,
    )
```

Note that you can also duplicate the layout of the mesh properties UVMap list with

`layout.template_list("MESH_UL_uvmaps", "uvmaps", obj.data, "uv_layers", obj.data.uv_layers, "active_index", rows=2)`

[image]

Comment: Ok, it works fine.

Comment: Can you help me in this https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/284841/how-to-add-udim-tiles-and-fill-in-python