# How to add UDIM tiles and fill them in blender 3.3 or below via python?

Tags: python, texturing

I want to add and fill the UDIM tiles only using the API and not `bpy.ops`.

I tried:

```
import bpy

udim_image = bpy.data.images.new('UDIM', 1024, 1024, tiled=True)
tile = udim_image.tiles.new(1002)
```

But it's neither fills the `udim_image` nor the `tile`